# How to make dropdown menu to select input from this code?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, html-select

today I have a code from my script but only make user to write down input to the fill with any value, so now I want to make it fixed

here is the original code

```
<div class="control-group">

<label for="input01" class="control-label">Enter the Amount  <i class="error_fnt">*</i></label>

<div class="controls">

<input type="text" name="amount" class="txtbig" value="<AJDF:output>$errval.amount</AJDF:output>">

</div></div>
```

the result above look like this : 
[image]

but I want to modify the above code so that we can select a fixed value like this as a dropdown menu but the fill able to receive an input:
[image]

thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean `<select>` ?

```html
<div class="control-group">

<label for="input01" class="control-label">Enter the Amount  <i class="error_fnt">*</i></label>

<div class="controls">


<select name = "amount" class = "form-control">
  <option>SELECT VALUE</option>
  <option value = "50">50</option>
  <option value = "150">150</option>
  <option value = "250">250</option>
  <option value = "500">500</option>
  <option value = "1000">1000</option>
  <option value = "5000">5000</option>
</select>
</div></div>
```